# Does the SSRS Report Server have a maximum number of columns it can cope with?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

I have an SSRS report with 21 tables. All occupy the same co-ordinates with a visibility property set to make a table show only if it's name is selected in the user interactive parameters.

I have been asked to add some columns to various tables. Having completed the amendments to the first two tables in the list of requests, I now can't upload the report to the report server, I get the good old Maximum request length exceeded error;

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

The strange thing is the size of the rdl file has barely increased over the past few changes, it's gone up by a few KB.

Here's the bit that prompted my question; if I reduce the overall number of columns by 3, so down to a total of 202 from 205, it lets me upload the report. Same if I remove an entire table of course.

This is a broad breakdown of what I'm asking the render engine to deal with if it helps;

[image: Report Breakdown]

Is there perhaps a setting in the web.config file that could be changed to fix this? Or another setting somewhere?

Failing that, I can see from my own table that some of them have the same structure and I could use all the parameters to amalgamate a chunk of them into one table, it's just that would be a significant amount of redevelopment time so I'm hoping for a setting based fix first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the web.config file on the server where SSRS has been installed, usually this is in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer or similar (depending on the version).

Make a backup of the web.config file.

Edit the web.config file, searching for "HttpRuntime".  There should be an execution timeout and request validation mode already present.  Add a new element called "maxRequestLength" and set it to a value in bytes.  I think the maximum length is 4MB by default, so to double this you could set it to 8388608.

The line would now look like this:

```
<HttpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" maxRequestLength="8388608" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Finally restart the SSRS service or reboot the server.